# Group Array Values based upon repeat values in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string

I have created an array whose values are as follows

```
size=[9, 41, 1368, 887, 307, 9, 114, 81, 9, 34, 12, 13, 12, 4, 548, 3, 77]
```

I need to group these values keeping a constant value = 9.

Example output required

Group 1

```
b=41
c=1368,887,307
```

Group 2

```
b=114
c=81
```

Group 3

```
b=34
c=12,13,12,4,548,3,77
```

I have no clue how to achieve this, i have tried out following code.

```
for i in range(0,len(size)):    
    if size[i-1]!=9:
        if(size[0]-size[i])!=0:
            print(size[i])
```

Comment: What exactly you want as output? You mention some groups with `b` and `c`, but I don't see any of that `b` and `c` or groups in your code? It just has `print`... Can you explain what the desired *output* would be of your code? Should it literally print "b=" or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to scan the input for those `9` values, and each time you encounter it, start a new list for gathering the other values.

Once you have those sublists, you can iterate those and report on the `b` and `c` parts of those:

```
size = [9, 41, 1368, 887, 307, 9, 114, 81, 9, 34, 
        12, 13, 12, 4, 548, 3, 77] 
# Spread data into sub lists, separated by 9-values
result = [[]]
for val in size:
    if val == 9:
        result.append([])  # Start a new sub list
    else:
        result[-1].append(val)  # Append to last sub list
# Remove empty sublists
result = [lst for lst in result if lst]
# Output in terms of b and c:
for b, *c in result:
    print("b=", b)
    print("c=", c)
```